# Converting values from for loop to json format

Tags: linux, unix

Below is a snippet of a for loop where I sort txt file names. I am then trying to save the results in a json format file. However it results in an invalid json format due to the last `,` inserted in `obj`. How could i convert to json format the values from the for loop?

script

```
dir = "myfiles/test/"
echo "[" >> test.json
for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
        #reverse the result of comparisons
        file=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | awk "NR==$i")
        [[ -n $file ]] && echo "{ \"filepath\" : \"$file\" },"  >> test.json
done
echo "]" >> test.json
```

Desired output

```
[
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/sdfsd.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/piids.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/saaad.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/smmnu.txt" }
]
```

Current output

```
[
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/sdfsd.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/piids.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/saaad.txt" },
{ "filepath" : "myfiles/test/smmnu.txt" },
]
```

Comment: not an elegant solution, but after you leave the loop, you could `sed -i '$s/,$//' test.json` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I will try that and it doesnt require an additional check inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that each line except the first begins with ",\n".

```
dir="myfiles/test/"

prefix=""
echo "[" >> test.json
for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
        #reverse the result of comparisons
        file=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | awk "NR==$i")
        [[ -n $file ]] && 
                printf '%b{ "filepath": "%s" }' $prefix "$file" >> test.json
        prefix=",\n"
done
echo
echo "]" >> test.json
```

Comment: Reconsidering this answer as the accepted one. It appears that it doesn't affect performance with additional checks and proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the work around for JSON conversion, but you can change your logic to get the desired o/p. Try adding it at start instead of end, but the extra check will affect the performance.

```
dir = "myfiles/test/"
flag = false
echo "[" >> test.json
for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
        #reverse the result of comparisons
        if [ $flag ]
            echo ","
        else
            flag = true
        fi
        file=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | awk "NR==$i")
        [[ -n $file ]] && echo -n "{ \"filepath\" : \"$file\" }"  >> test.json
done
echo "]" >> test.json
```

Comment: what shell is this? with var assignment like `flag = false` (spaces around `=`) this is not legal syntax for `bash/ksh/sh`. Good luck to all.