# Shell while loop to JSON

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a while loop with two variables I have to merge into a single piece of JSON, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r from to
do
    # BONUS: Solution would ideally require no quoting at this point
    echo { \"From\": \"$from\", \"To\": \"$to\" } 
done << EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF
```

Which currently outputs invalid JSON:

```
{ "From": "foo", "To": "bar" }
{ "From": "what", "To": "ever" }
```

What's the simplest I can create valid JSON like:

```
[
{ "From": "foo", "To": "bar" },
{ "From": "what", "To": "ever" }
]
```

I looked at `jq` but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm not [looking to do it in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923164/4534) ideally because I feel adding commas and such is a bit ugly.

Comment: Ugliness is not the problem in shell. The problem is that without knowing the contents of `$from` and `$to`, you cannot guarantee that the values are properly quoted JSON values, at least not easily. Also, you should at least use `printf '{ "From": "%s", "To": "%s" }' "$from" "$to"` to handle the issues that can be handled by the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jq:

```
$ jq -nR '[inputs | split(" ") | {"From": .[0], "To": .[1]}]' <<EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF

[
  {
    "From": "foo",
    "To": "bar"
  },
  {
    "From": "what",
    "To": "ever"
  }
]
```

`-n` tells jq to not read any input; `-R` is for raw input so it doesn't expect JSON.

The input is read with `inputs`, resulting in one string per input line:

```
$ jq -nR 'inputs' <<EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF
"foo bar"
"what ever"
```

These are then split into arrays of words:

```
$ jq -nR 'inputs | split(" ")' <<EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF

[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]
[
  "what",
  "ever"
]
```

From this, we construct the objects:

```
$ jq -nR 'inputs | split(" ") | {"From": .[0], "To": .[1]}' <<EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF

{
  "From": "foo",
  "To": "bar"
}
{
  "From": "what",
  "To": "ever"
}
```

And finally, we wrap everything in `[]` to get the final output shown first.

The more intuitive approach of splitting input directly fails because wrapping everything in `[]` results in one array per input line:

```
$ jq -R '[split(" ") | { "From": .[0], "To": .[1] }]' <<EOF
foo bar
what ever
EOF

[
  {
    "From": "foo",
    "To": "bar"
  }
]
[
  {
    "From": "what",
    "To": "ever"
  }
]
```

Hence the somewhat cumbersome `-n`/`inputs`. Notice that `inputs` requires jq version 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an all-jq solution that assumes the "From" and "To" values are presented exactly as in your example:

```
jq -R -n '[inputs | split(" ") | {From: .[0], To: .[1]}]'
```

You might want to handle additional spaces using `gsub/2`.

If your jq does not have `inputs` then you can use this incantation:

```
jq -R -s 'split("\n")
  | map(select(length>1) | split(" ") | {From: .[0], To: .[1]})'
```

Or you could just pipe the output from your while-loop into `jq -s`.